# How to make a component show different value according to the vue instance it is in?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I have nested the component in both app and app2 divs. I was expecting this component will show value based on the vue instance. Please show the right way to do this. Thanks a lot.

```
var aboutPageComponent = {
    template: "<div><h1>{{ whatPage }}</h1><p>{{ itsMe }}</p></div>",
    data: function(){
        return{
            whatPage: "This is About Page"

        }
    },
    methods: {

    }
}



var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        itsMe: "This is vm talking"

    },
    methods: {

    },
    components: {
        "app_about": aboutPageComponent
    }
});

var vm2 = new Vue({
    el: "#app2",
    data: {
        itsMe: "This is vm2 talking"

    },
    methods: {

    },
    components: {
        "app_about": aboutPageComponent
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `app_about` does not know what `itsMe` is.

But you can pass a `itsMe` as a prop via the `props` option.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var aboutPageComponent = {
  template: "<div><h1>{{ whatPage }}</h1><p>{{ itsMe }}</p></div>",
  props: ["itsMe"],
  data: function() {
    return {
      whatPage: "This is About Page"

    }
  }
}

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    itsMe: "This is vm talking"
  },
  components: {
    "app_about": aboutPageComponent
  }
});

var vm2 = new Vue({
  el: "#app2",
  data: {
    itsMe: "This is vm2 talking"
  },
  components: {
    "app_about": aboutPageComponent
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <app_about :its-me="itsMe" />
</div>

<div id="app2">
  <app_about :its-me="itsMe" />
</div>
```